# iOS Objective-C: How to call Push Segue from another Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

**Scenario**

I have an app that displays posts to users in a UITableViewController - and inside certain posts that contains comments there will be *another* UITableView inside that cell to display the comments. Each comment the will contain a profile picture that is underneath a UIButton. When this UIButton is pushed I want the UITableViewController class to segue to another UIViewController that will display info about that user that made the post.

**So, To recap**

`UITableViewController` **will perform the Push Segue**

`UITableViewController` has `UITableViewCells`

`UITableViewCells` *(that contain comments)* will have a child `UITableView`

`UITableView` will contain cells itself, each with a `UIButton`

when `UIButton` is pushed, `UITableViewController` **will perform the Push Segue**

**What I've Tried**

```
- (void)ProfilePictureWasPushed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSDictionary *object = [self.comments objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    DashboardViewController *dashboard = [[DashboardViewController alloc]init];
    dashboard.selectedID = object[@"posterID"];
    [dashboard performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:dashboard];

}
```

I get this error...

```
...reason: 'Receiver (<DashboardViewController: 0x7d867600>) has no segue with identifier 'profile''
```

I have checked and there in fact is a push segue that is called "profile".

**Question**

Does anyone know how to properly perform this feat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIViewControllers initiating and receiving the segues must be loaded using storyboard according to the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:

*The view controller that receives this message must have been loaded from a storyboard. If the view controller does not have an associated storyboard, perhaps because you allocated and initialized it yourself, this method throws an exception.*

If you want to segue from ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB, then you need to invoke the method on an instance of ViewControllerA. Also you should not be creating the ViewControllerB. So your code should be

```
- (void)ProfilePictureWasPushed:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profile" sender:sender]; //self could also be used for sender
}
```

As you also want to pass data to the destination view controller via segue, To do this override the -prepareForSegue:sender in the source view controller (i.e. your UITableViewController), retrieve the destinationViewController and set the selectedID.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
     if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"profile"]]) {
         NSDictionary *object = [self.comments objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
         DashboardViewController *dashboard = (DashboardViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
         dashboard.selectedID = object[@"posterID"];
      }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a very belated check for this answer (been like over a year) but you were still correct. It was quite obvious looking back now what the issues were and you outlined them perfectly. I feel silly even having asked it now, but I'll keep it up for other users if it helps them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'profile' segue identifier is located on DashboardViewController?? Please check it on Main.storyboard of your project.

Example : 
'poster' segue on this project located on MyViewController Scene

Answer (score 0):

The string "profile" should be assigned explicitly in the storyboard. Select the segue in the interface builder and go to the Attributes Inspector and check if the Indetifier is defined and correctly spelled.